# Outlook Addin - ItemProperties.Add change the mail format

Tags: c#, email, outlook, mailitem

I am trying to add an Item Property as follow:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemProperty property = currentMail.ItemProperties.Add("isCopy", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olYesNo);
property.Value = false;
```

The issue is that it is changing the email format.

Before adding this property the email was sent as follow:

> Formatted
>   [image]

After adding this property the email are sent as follow:

> No Formatted and with attached file
>   [image]

Furthermore, I have already tried UserProperties.Add. The behavior is the same.

Comment: Do you need to user property to be attached to the message is it goes to the destination? Or you just want it stored in the local copy of the message?

Comment: I don't need it to go to the destination. But I need to access this data in case of the user keep the email in Draft for future update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a user property causes Outlook to send message in the TNEF (RTF) format (the infamous winmail.dat).

You can either set the property by the DASL name using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty` (instead of using `UserProperties.Add`) or set a special `UseTnef` named property to false using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8582000B", false)` before calling Send.

Comment: Thank you so much! I already tested it and it works. I should just set the property in this way: `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/string/{FFF40745-D92F-4C11-9E14-92701F001EB3}/myPropertyName", value);`. It is about the valid Namespace.

Comment: The GUID can be anything you want - as long as you use the same value. UserProperties coleldtion uses the PS_PUBLIC_STRINGS guid.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented some not elegant workaround just for not be stuck.

As I told before, I need to know whether the MailItem is a copy or not. So I am saving the EntryID in a List of copies.

Object X:

```
thisAddIn.AddEntryIdCopy(mailItem.EntryID);
```

Object Y:

```
thisAddIn.ContainsEntryIdCopy(mailItem.EntryID)
```

**Ps.:** Due to the fact that the EntryId is changed when the MailItem is moved to a different folder, this way will work as long as the MailItem is in the same folder.